# How can i load a picture with jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, image

i am currently working on a class that generates diagrams as pictures with php. I want to load these pictures dynamically with jquery. How can i do that?? I wont have a real picture file, just the content of the file when i call it with ajax... And i cant simply define the php script as the src because i need to pass Post parameters to the picture...

EDIT:

Okay.. I think i have to explain it a bit further...

Here is the html code:

```
<div>
<img id="image" />
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="loadPicture();" />
```

When the button is pressed, some data should be send to the php script that generates the picture. A Callback function or something similar should now post the picture into the img- element.
Simply posting the Picture into the img tag doesnt work. The following code would work, but how can i add POST params??

```
<img src="<scriptname>.php" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "post params" ? As I was saying below the jQuery .post method can accept parameters and it returns the result as callback. Here you can find more about this: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post

Comment: I mean Parameters which are send in within a post header. i know the $.post function, but i dont really know what the response should look like. I cant pass a image path, because the image doesnt exist, i cant pass the image itself because i cant display it then (i dont know a way to display it)...

Answer (score 3):

Http POST requests aren't meant to return resources. Why don't you use a GET request? The 'REST' way to do it will be to create the image with a POST request and then load it with a GET request. You need to define a URL mapping for your resources.

Comment: The problem in using GET is, in IE the length of the URL is limited... but i may have pretty much data that need to be processed to create the image... so i definitley will reach the max length of the IE (2048 chars i think... )

Comment: It is not a good idea to use lengthy GET requests either. Just do it in two steps. 'Create' the image with the POST request. Return a unique identifier as the result. Then do a GET with this identifier. You can either save the image in a temp file or save the POST parameters in the http session.

Answer (score 2):

No people! You basically have 3 options as I see it.

#### Method 1 - Inline the image

Do what Brayn said, but `data` should be a [base64 encoding of your image](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html).

```
$("#div").html(data); // instead of this
$('#image').attr('src','data:image/gif;base64,'+data); // try something like this
```

But I don't like the idea of inlining the image or passing post data. Base64 might get a bit large for big images too.

#### Method 2 - Save the image

You can `$.post` the data like before, then **save** the image, and return the URL of the image.

#### Method 3 - Use GET

Modify your image-generating script to accept `GET` data. If you have a lot of data to pass, try compressing it somehow, or *perhaps* you can use `SESSION` variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure if I got it right from what you said but you could use the $.post() method that would return whatever you need through its callback. Something like this:

```
$.post("file.php",{param: val},function(data){
    $("#div").html(data);
})
```

If you could explain further maybe we'll understand better. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you have to send POST params (i.e., if GET won't work in your situation) this is the most reasonable answer to your problem. In this example 'data' would be the HTML image tag with the correct image src returned as by PHP. If you need more information on how that works, ask and I will elaborate on what Brayn has posted (or if he wants to, he can...).

Answer (score 0):

Is there any actual need to use AJAX / jQuery? Or are you simply putting it in because it's cool?

Here's what I would do:

```
if (isset($_POST['createImage'])){
    // This means that the button was clicked
    // Generate your image, and then display it:
}

// Regardless, you would now show your form
// That way if values were to be changed, the graphic can be recalculated.
```

This way, you achieve your desired output (the graphic loading depending on the form output) and a single click to generate that output.